# How to see who the individual is who registers multiple people for a paid event

Tags: civievent

Where in Civi can I see who paid for/registered themselves and multiple other people for a paid event?  In other words, if Joe registers and also registers his two friends Gary and Bill for the same event how do I see that Joe paid for/registered Gary and Bill?

CiviCRM v4.5.8 with WP 4.2.2

Comment: I'd like to add if there could be clarification on if there is a difference when a profile is skipped if not required.

Answer (score 2):

Results from CiviCRM demo (4.5 on Drupal)

- Additional participants do not have a contribution source, so they can be identified on a Event Participants List Report (you will need to select the Contribution source in the report criteria)
- Click view on the participant and "Registered By" will be shown.
- Clicking the "Registered By" participant will take you the that person's registration showing all the people he/she registered.

Comment: Ok.  Is there anyway to get the "Registered By" on a report?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can't get a report, per se, but you can do an Advanced Search and view the search results as participants. You can then export the search results and select the 'Registered By ID' as one of the export fields. You should be able to use a pivot table to group the data accordingly.